# Daemon::Generic locks disappearing upon daemonization on Solaris

Tags: perl, locking, solaris, daemon, file-locking

I'm trying to use [Daemon::Generic](http://search.cpan.org/~muir/Daemon-Generic-0.82/lib/Daemon/Generic.pod), and it seems to be exactly what I need, except on Solaris it seems that locking the pid file doesn't work. As a result, `status` always reports the process is dead, even when it is quite clearly alive.

For example, the following:

```
use Daemon::Generic;

sub gd_run
{
  sleep (60);
}

sub gd_preconfig
{
  return ();
}

newdaemon(pidfile => "/tmp/myproc.pid");
```

... always reports the process is dead.

Note that `/tmp` is mounted locally, so it seems like that should avoid issues with locks over network drives.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

**Edit:**

On closer investigation, by putting `sleep 60` commands at various points in `Generic.pm`, that it seems the lock is lost somewhere in the function `gd_daemonize`. Do locks not survive forks on Solaris? Is there a way to ensure the lock survives the `daemonize` process?